# How to check if a given date format is present list of date formats using python?

Tags: python, list, date, date-format, any

I need help in checking if the given date is present in the date format of a list. I have a list of date formats. I want to check if a given date is present in that date format. How do I do that? However, I tried doing it though getting an error.

My code:

```
x = "03-24-2019"
Date = ['%Y/%m/%d','%Y-%m-%d','%Y%m%d','%m/%d/%Y','%m-%d-%Y']
if x in any(Date):
    print(Date)
else:
    print('no')
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Execpted Output:

```
%m-%d-%Y
```

Comment: `any(Date)` is just `True`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney oh, How do I match it then?

Comment: Write a parser. Based on number range and number separators get a format. Then check that string format in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The below should work.

The idea is to loop over formats and try to call `strptime`

```
from datetime import datetime

x = "03-24-2019"
date_formats = ['%Y/%m/%d', '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%m%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m-%d-%Y']
for date_format in date_formats:
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(x, date_format)
        print(date_format)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
```

output

```
%m-%d-%Y
```